# How can I generate good looking png-images out of latex?

Tags: latex, equation

I'm trying to generate png-images out of latex code because I need this function for a webproject. My goal is to achieve something like [codecogs][1]
I don't mean the whole editor but only the functionality of the image generation.
Do you know how this is solved on the website?

My attempt was some kind of tex to image generator, respectively I decided to use this. I think these are really nice looking pngs. But I don't get it to run!
So I have problems in implementing. (for information: I'm using Windows)

Furthermore is it correct, that this is client-side program?

Comment: Did you take a look at [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) ? It's for web LaTeX...

Comment: Yeah I implemented this library and it works, but I want create nevertheless a png output. And this isn´t possible with MathJax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following Makefile for my LaTeX graphic projects:

```
SOURCE = symbol
DELAY = 80
DENSITY = 300
WIDTH = 512

make:
    pdflatex $(SOURCE).tex -output-format=pdf
    make clean

clean:
    rm -rf  $(TARGET) *.class *.html *.log *.aux *.data *.gnuplot

gif:
    pdfcrop $(SOURCE).pdf
    convert -verbose -delay $(DELAY) -loop 0 -density $(DENSITY) $(SOURCE)-crop.pdf $(SOURCE).gif
    make clean

png:
    make svg
    inkscape $(SOURCE).svg -w $(WIDTH) --export-png=$(SOURCE).png

transparentGif:
    convert $(SOURCE).pdf -transparent white result.gif
    make clean

svg:
    make
    #inkscape $(SOURCE).pdf --export-plain-svg=$(SOURCE).svg
    pdf2svg $(SOURCE).pdf $(SOURCE).svg
    # Necessary, as pdf2svg does not always create valid svgs:
    #inkscape $(SOURCE).svg --export-plain-svg=$(SOURCE).svg
```

### Without Makefile

1. Generate PDF: `pdflatex source.tex -output-format=pdf`
2. Generate SVG: `pdf2svg source.pdf source.svg`
3. Generate PNG: `inkscape source.svg -w source --export-png=source.png`

Incscape can also directly convert PDF to PNG.

Another option is [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) from ImageMagick

Comment: But can I use this only if I have access to an Unix-like operating systems on my Web-Server?

Comment: No, you just a way to generate a PDF from latex source and inkscape or imagemagick. That should be possible on all systems (Linux, Windows, Mac).